# $\int ^{\infty}_0 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 + 2x+ 4}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

We have to find the integration of

$$\int ^{\infty}_0 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 + 2x+ 4}dx$$

In this I tried to do substitution of $x=e^t$

After that got stuck .

Comment: $$\int ^{\infty}_0 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 + 2x+ 4} \mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{u e^u}{e^{2u} + 2e^u+ 4} \mathrm du$$

Comment: @DHMO how does this help?

Comment: @gt6989b Not really. I'm just expanding his attempt.

Comment: You can use contour integration if that is suitable for you.

Comment: thats defiantly the easiest way to approach it also that substitution doesn't look right ^^ should just be a u on top no? any chance partial fractions would help?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai what is contour integration

Comment: $$x+1=\sqrt3\tan y$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee will this substitution not become very complicated ?

Comment: I have a way but the result will be too long

Comment: @ArchisWelankar what ?

Comment: I dont think there is much better way. Also you can try tan(t)  as the integral is an improper one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

May be this will be a more elementary solution.

Let us start with a the substitution $x=2y$. Then
\begin{gather*}
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^2+2x+4}\, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}2\dfrac{\ln(2y)}{4y^2+4y+4}\, dy =\\[2ex] \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(2)}{y^2+y+1}\, dy + \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln y}{y^2+y+1}\, dy=
\dfrac{\ln(2)}{2}I_1+ \dfrac{1}{2}I_2\tag{1}
\end{gather*}
where
\begin{equation*}
I_1 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{y^2+y+1}\, dy =\dfrac{4}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{2y+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2}+1}\, dy = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan\left(\dfrac{2y+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} = \dfrac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
I_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(y)}{y^2+y+1}\, dy =\left[y=\dfrac{1}{z}\right] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{-\ln(z)}{z^2+z+1}\, dz = -I_2. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
But (3) implies that $I_2=0$. This and (2) substituted in (1) give us $I = \dfrac{\pi\ln(2)}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $I$ be defined by the integral

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx \tag1$$

and let $J$ be the contour integral

$$J=\oint_{C}\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2+2z+4}\,dz \tag2$$

where the contour $C$ is the classical "key-hole" contour for which the keyhole coincides with the branch cut along the positive real axis.

Then, we can write $(2)$ as

$$\begin{align}
J&=\int_0^R \frac{\log^2(x)}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx-\int_0^R \frac{(\log(x)+i2\pi)^2}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx+\int_{C_R}\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2+2z+4}\,dz\\\\
&=-i4\pi \int_0^R \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx+4\pi^2\int_0^R\frac{1}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx+\int_{C_R}\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2+2z+4}\,dz\tag 3
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$ the integral over $C_R$ vanishes and we have from $(1)$

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}J=-i4\pi I +4\pi^2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx\tag 4$$

---

Next, we apply the residue theorem to evaluate the left-hand side of $(4)$.  Proceeding we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to \infty}J&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2+2z+4}\,dz, z=-1\pm i\sqrt{3}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{(\log(2)+i2\pi/3)^2}{i2\sqrt{3}}+\frac{(\log(2)+i4\pi/3)^2}{-i2\sqrt{3}}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{i4\pi^2\log(2)}{3\sqrt{3}}+\frac{4\pi^3}{3\sqrt{3}}\tag 5
\end{align}$$

Equating real and imaginary parts of $(3)$ and $(5)$ reveals

> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx =\frac{\pi \log(2)}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

and as a bonus

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

And we are done!

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for providing such a good answer . But I am unable to understand it . As I have never studied countor integration . I am just a high school student .

Comment: @Koolman You're very welcome.  And apology if this solution was beyond the scope of the current level of your courses.  Was this a problem given in high school?  -Mark

Comment: It was my mistake , I should have already mention that . Yes it is high school problem .

Comment: What tools have you learned in integration techniques?

Comment: Integration as the inverse process of differentiation, indefinite integrals of standard functions, definite integrals and their properties, Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus.

Integration by parts, integration by the methods of substitution and partial fractions, application of definite integrals to the determination of areas involving simple curves.

Formation of ordinary differential equations, solution of homogeneous differential equations, separation of variables method, linear first order differential equations.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$I = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\ln x}{x^2+2x+4}dx = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\ln x}{(x+1)^2+(\sqrt{3})^2}dx$$

put $\displaystyle x=\frac{1^2+(\sqrt{3})^2}{y} = \frac{4}{y}$ and $\displaystyle dx = -\frac{4}{y^2}dy$

$$I = \int^{0}_{\infty}\frac{\ln (4)-\ln (y)}{16+8y+4y^2}\cdot -\frac{4}{y^2}\cdot y^2 dy = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\ln 4-\ln y}{y^2+2y+4}dy$$

$$I = \ln 4\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{(y+1)^2+(\sqrt{3})^2}dy-I$$

So $$I = \ln 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\bigg|^{\infty}_{0} = \frac{\ln 2}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}\bigg) = \frac{\pi \cdot \ln 2}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\quad r \equiv -1 + \root{3}\ic\quad\mbox{and}\quad  R > 0}$,

Hereafter, $\ds{\ln\pars{z}}$ is the *principal $\ds{\ln}$-branch cut*.
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{4R}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 2x + 4} & =
\int_{0}^{4R}\ln\pars{x}\pars{{1 \over x - r} - {1 \over x - \bar{r}}}
{1 \over r - \bar{r}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{0}^{4R}{\ln\pars{x} \over x - r}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
\Im\int_{0}^{4R}{\ln\pars{x} \over x - r}\,\dd x & =
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{4R}{\ln\pars{r\bracks{x/r}} \over 1 - x/r}\,{\dd x \over r} =
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{4R/r}{\ln\pars{rx} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x =
-\,\Im\int_{0}^{R\bar{r}}{\ln\pars{rx} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
 \\[5mm] & =
-\,\Im\bracks{-\ln\pars{1 - R\,\bar{r}}\ln\pars{4R} +
\int_{0}^{R\bar{r}}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\Im\bracks{-\ln\pars{1 - R\,\bar{r}}\ln\pars{4R} -
\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{R\,\bar{r}}}
\end{align}

---

With $\quad$ [$\ds{\,\mrm{Li}_{2}}$*-Inversion Formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm)$\quad$ and $\ds{\quad R\,\bar{r} \not\in \left[0,1\right)}$:
\begin{align}
\Im\int_{0}^{4R}{\ln\pars{x} \over x - r}\,\dd x & =
\Im\braces{\ln\pars{1 - R\,\bar{r}}\ln\pars{4R} +
\bracks{-\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over R\,\bar{r}} - {\pi^{2} \over 6} -
{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{-R\bar{r}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\Im\braces{\ln\pars{1 - R\,\bar{r}}\ln\pars{4R} -
{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{-R\,\bar{r}}
- \,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over R\,\bar{r}}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\Im\int_{0}^{4R}{\ln\pars{x} \over x - r}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&
\Im\braces{\ln\pars{1 + R + R\root{3}\ic}\ln\pars{4R} -
{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{R + R\root{3}\ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\arctan\pars{{R \over 1 + R}\root{3}}\ln\pars{4R} -
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\pars{\bracks{%
\ln\pars{2R} + \arctan\pars{\root{3}}\ic}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\arctan\pars{{R \over 1 + R}\root{3}}\ln\pars{4R} -
\ln\pars{2R}\,\arctan\pars{\root{3}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,&
\bbx{\ds{{1 \over 3}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

With \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}:
$$
\bbx{\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 2x + 4} =
{\root{3} \over 9}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}} \approx 0.4191
$$